# how do I run a bat file using AutoIT?

Tags: autoit

I've seen examples online

```
Run("\\FullPath\To\Exe\File.exe", "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

I want to run the file from the "same folder" the Exe is

```
Run(CurrentDirectory & "\File.exe", "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code works fine

```
Run(@ScriptDir & "\File.exe", "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

try using this

```
ShellExecute(@ScriptDir & "\File.exe")
```

or

```
ShellExecute(@ScriptDir & "\File.bat")
```

for batch files

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to use the @ScriptDir to give you (untested)

```
Run(@ScriptDir & "\File.exe", "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

The @ScriptDir macro returns the location where the script is located.